# Why is form action called before proper validation of the form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

```
<script language="javascript">
    function startTime(){
        var today = new Date();
        var h = today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "Current Time: " + h + 
        ":" + m + ":" + s;
        var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
    }

    function checkForAnswers(){
        alert('Hi');
        if((document.f1.q1[0].checked==false)&& 
        (document.f1.q1[1].checked==false)&& 
        (document.f1.q1[2].checked==false)&& 
        (document.f1.q1[3].checked==false))
            alert('Please attend all the questions!')
        else if((document.f1.q2[0].checked==false)&& 
        (document.f1.q2[1].checked==false)&& 
        (document.f1.q2[2].checked==false)&& 
        (document.f1.q2[3].checked==false))
            alert('Please attend all the questions!')
        else
            alert('Thanks');
    }

</script>
<body onload="startTime()">
    <p id="time"></p>
    <form action="results.php" method="post" name="f1">
    <p><b>Quiz</b></p>
    <p>1. What is the capital of India?</p>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-A" value="A">Delhi<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-B" value="B">Chennai<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-C" value="C">Mumbai<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-D" value="D">Kolkata<br/>
    <p>2. What is the capital of USA?</p>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2-A" value="A">Miami<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2-B" value="B">Houston<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2-C" value="C">Washington DC<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2-D" value="D">Palo Alto<br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button" onclick="checkForAnswers()">
    </form>
</body>
```

I'm trying to create a simple quiz like application using PHP and to check if all the questions are answered, I wrote a function called `checkForAnswers()` and have called it on the button's `onClick()` and it works(shows alert) but, instead of staying on the same page, it proceeds to `results.php` where PHP errors are shown.

I also cannot use a button here instead of a submit because of the PHP.

What do I do now? Please help me with this!

Comment: You need to stop the default action of the submit. ie. at the end of your `checkForAnswers()` function add a `return false;`

Comment: First, make your Input type submit button a regular button, so it doesn't actually submit the form. Then in your validation routine checkForAnswers, if everything passes, manually submit the form with document.getElementsByName("f1").submit();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign your function to the form's onsubmit and make your function return false. return true only if you want to proceed

```
<form action="results.php" method="post" name="f1" onsubmit="return checkForAnswers()">
```

EDIT: return checkForAnswers() would work

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function startTime(){
        var today = new Date();
        var h = today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "Current Time: " + h +
            ":" + m + ":" + s;
        var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
    }

    function checkForAnswers(e){    
        alert('Hi');
        if(!document.f1.q1.value) {
            alert('Please attend all the questions!');
            return false;
        }
        else if(!document.f1.q2.value) {
            alert('Please attend all the questions!')
            return false;
        }

        alert('Thanks');
        return true;
    }

</script>
<body onload="startTime()">
<p id="time"></p>
<form action="results.php" method="post" name="f1" onsubmit="return checkForAnswers();">
    <p><b>Quiz</b></p>
    <p>1. What is the capital of India?</p>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-A" value="A">Delhi<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-B" value="B">Chennai<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-C" value="C">Mumbai<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-D" value="D">Kolkata<br/>
    <p>2. What is the capital of USA?</p>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2-A" value="A">Miami<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2-B" value="B">Houston<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2-C" value="C">Washington DC<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2-D" value="D">Palo Alto<br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button">
</form>
</body>
```

It will run your function on submit (instead of just the button press).  If the function returns false, it will stay on the page with the errors alerted, if not, it will get submitted.